# What would be the proper way to handle SVG file manipulation when using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, svg

In an AngularJS application, what would be the proper way to handle SVG file manipulation? Reason for me bringing up AngularJS is that I have read that mixing jQuery and AngularJS is not a good idea.

I have a map that I have been able to load doing the following:

```
<object height="600" width="800" data="/images/map.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
```

An example of a `<path>` that represents a country:

```
  <path class="land ly" d="bunch of coordinates here..." id="country_id"/>
```

I have been able to fill a country with a different color when the cursor is over it with a CSS rule, like this:

```
.country_id:hover {
  opacity:    1;
  fill:       #ff0000;
}
```

Now, I would like to trigger a Javascript function when a country is being clicked, how could I handle that, keeping in mind that jQuery would not be a great solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick attribute to the path element e.g. onclick="alert('hello!');"